# Render custom entity type field in form (Symfony)

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, twig

I got stuck while trying to customize the rendering of a specific field in my form.
It looks like this:

```
$builder->add('players', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\Player',
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        'required' => false,
    ));
```

The form itself is beeing rendered with a simple:

```
{% block form_content %}
    {% form_theme form 'AcmeBundle:Form:fields_child.html.twig' %}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Now inside fields_child.html.twig i'm extending from another form template but there is nothing special there. 
My HTML looks like this:

Players: 
 - [checkbox-input] 1

Where 1 equals the id of the only player in the database. However instead of rendering the ID im trying to render his picture and full name after the checkbox.
I have tried many combinations of the form theming to override it but failed each time.
Could someone post the twig block to render what i want here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your `AcmeBundle:Form:fields_child.html.twig`? :)

Comment: Nothing to see there, it's an empty template where the missing block should be put to render the players. I tried several block names but couldnt find anything that works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create custom form field type together with custom widget template for it.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: Are you suggesting to make a form PlayerType and using it in the following matter?
 
   $builder->add('players', new PlayerType());

Where playertype will have entity as a parent type? The template will still require rendering of the checkboxes and so i will have to override the complete widget and dropping the default "choice" rendering block. Correct?

Comment: I will try to implement this in a couple of days, short on time now. I have created custom form types before but tbh i didnt think this was to solution for my problem. We will see

Comment: Not a form type, but field type (technically it's the same but ..), you should use it like this: `$builder->add('players', 'your_custom_type', array(...))`

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem (was a little bit different situation. I needed to show products as table with checkboxes..), Form's child data always returned null value that's why I ended up with this (dirty:)) solution:

Controller action:

```
...
$productRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('VendorMyBundle:Product');

$products = [];
$formChildren = $productListForm->createView()->children;
foreach ($formChildren['products'] as $formProduct) {
    $formProductId = $formProduct->vars['value'];
    $productEntity = $productRepository->find($formProductId);
    $products[$formProductId] = $productEntity;
}
...
return $this->render('TEMPLATE', [
    'productListForm' => $productListForm->createView(),
    'products' => $products,
]);
```

Template:

```
...
     {% for productForm in productListForm.products %}
        {% set id = productForm.vars.value %}
        <tr>
            <td class="check">
                {{ form_widget(productForm) }}
            </td>

            <td class="photo">
                {% if products[id].getImages().isEmpty() == false %}
                    {% set productImage = products[id].getImages().first() %}
                    <img src="{{ productImage.getWebPath() | imagine_filter('st_product_cabinet_thumbnail') }}" />
                {% else %}
                    <span class="no-image">No image</span>
                {% endif %}
            </td>

            <td class="title">
                <a href="{{ path('ROUT', {'productSlug':products[id].getSlug()}) }}" target="_blank">{{ products[id].getName() }}</a>
            </td>

            <td class="status">
                {{ products[id].getStatusName(products[id].getStatus()) }}
            </td>

            <td class="price">
                <ul>
                    {% for productPrice in products[id].getPrices() %}
                        <li>{{ productPrice.getValue() ~ ' ' ~ productPrice.getCurrencyCode() }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    ...
```